# Getting a space error when trying to save site as a template

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template

When I try to save a SharePoint site as template I am getting the following error:

> Sorry, something went wrong 
>   Error creating solution. The maximum total file size limit (52428800 bytes) has been exceeded.

Please note I am using SharePoint online and not SharePoint on prem. In addition, I have the "include content" option unselected.

Comment: Templates are a tad sucky. Use the PnP provisioning engine https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Provisioning-Schema/tree/master/Samples (requires a little PS skill but examples are detailed and easy to follow). It can do everything you need and much more.

Comment: Is it a modern site?

Answer (score 0):

When we create a template of a site and include greater than 50 MB of content will result in an error message stating “Error creating solution. The maximum total file size limit (52428800 bytes) has been exceeded.”

The default size limit for a site template is 50 MB in SharePoint online. This value cannot be changed in SharePoint Online.

Reference:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-use-site-templates-60371b0f-00e0-4c49-a844-34759ebdd989?CorrelationId=67e2f12e-84b6-4962-a3a1-27e109b31e68&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102756445